# reshape dataframe with missing values in tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataframe like:

```
library(tidyverse) 

df_mess <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~value, ~answer_text,
  123,     25,        "age",
  123,     NA,     "female",
  234,     29,        "age",
  234,     NA,       "male",
  345,     14,        "age",
  345,     NA,     "female"
  )
```

I would like to reshape in a way to have "tidy" data, aka 1 row for each observation.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~age,     ~sex,
  123,   25, "female",
  234,   29,   "male",
  345,   14, "female"
  )
```

I tried a version of `gather` / `spread`, but I had no luck.

Any lead is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @xxxvinxxx. I just wanted to check in and see if the answer provided solved your problem. If not, would you mind telling us why it didn't? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with spread and gather. The `spread` will get all variables like `age` where the name of the variable appears in the answer_text column. If the values of the variable are in the answer_text column (like sex in this case), you will need to `gather` these back like below.

In order to get the sex column to work, I changed the `NAs` in `value` to -99. You could use any value though. If you spread without something in the `value` column, it will show as `NA` in the `female` and `male` columns that are created from the spread.

```
df_mess[is.na(df_mess)] <- -99

df_mess %>% 
  spread(answer_text, value) %>% 
  gather(sex, temp, female, male, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-temp)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id   age sex   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1   123    25 female
2   345    14 female
3   234    29 male
```

Example with more variables and a legitimate `NA` in the `size` variable for `id` 123.

```
   df_mess <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~value, ~answer_text,
  123,     25,        "age",
  123,     NA,     "female",
  234,     29,        "age",
  234,     NA,       "male",
  345,     14,        "age",
  345,     NA,     "female",
  123,     NA,      "brown",
  234,     NA,     "blonde",
  345,     NA,      "black",
  123,     NA,       "size",
  234,     30,       "size",
  345,     40,       "size",

)
df_mess[is.na(df_mess)] <- -99
df_clean <- df_mess %>% 
  spread(answer_text, value) %>% 
  gather(sex, temp, female, male, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-temp) %>% 
  gather(hair, temp, black:brown, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-temp)

df_clean[df_clean == -99] <- NA
df_clean
```

output

```
     id   age  size sex    hair  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
1   345    14    40 female black 
2   234    29    30 male   blonde
3   123    25    NA female brown
```

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the your data is always the same I would do something like:

```
df_mess$new <- lead(df_mess$answer_text)
df_mess <- subset(df_mess,df_mess$value>0)
```

but this is a possible solution only for this particular case.